# Jquery AJAX Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

A plain Jquery ajax request is throwing this error :

`SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' …     }↵}' is not a valid HTTP header field value.`

`$.ajax({url : '/ajax'})`

I have tested this with a normal javascript xmlhttp request and it works fine. Any ideas what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

you're sending setrequestheader as a header key, so your syntax is wrong. if you're using $.get(); you need to use $.ajaxSetup({}); and include the below method, or to avoid using a global setup for all your further ajax calls use $.ajax({}); and include your ajax settings within that specific wrapper.

you can set your request header with beforesend method of jquery ajax like this:

```
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'bla bla');}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this happens with `$.ajax' as well.  I can't see why, as it normally functions fine.

Comment: can you update your question and mention exactly how you set your request header?

Comment: i'm guessing you're setting up your request header somewhere in your code prior to this stage in a $.ajaxSetup({}); wrapper, which causing an error here. the error is clearly complaining about setrequestheader syntax which you set somewhere before.

Comment: No, none of my code is changing the header request, the ajax call is the only function.  Could it have anything todo with the way jQuery is included?

Comment: if your jQuery lib has been manually modified and jquery build is failing itself, yes it could.

Comment: i'd suggest you to provide a bigger picture as to see what's causing the issue.

Comment: Got it, my own lib was interfering, serves me right ;).  Thanks anyway.